# Relation between Fundamental theorem of calculus and the definition of the derivative

Tags: calculus

What is the link/relation between the fundamental theorem of calculus and the definition of the derivative?

Comment: One link is that you have to know the definition of 'derivative" to understand the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that given a continuous function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ which is differentiable on $(a,b)$, if we define $F:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ by $$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\ \mathsf dt$$ then $F$ is differentiable and $F'=f$. By the definition of the derivative, this means that for $x\in(a,b)$, $$\lim_{y\to x}\frac{F(y)-F(x)}{y-x} = f(x). $$ To see this, given $\varepsilon>0$ we may choose $\delta>0$ so that $0<|y-x|<\delta$ implies $|f(y)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ (by continuity of $f$). So when $0<|y-x|<\delta$,
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{F(y)-F(x)}{y-x} - f(x) \right| &= \left|\frac{\int_a^y f(t)\ \mathsf dt-\int_a^x f(t)\ \mathsf dt}{y-x}-\frac{f(x)(y-x)}{y-x} \right|\\ &= \left|\frac{\int_x^y f(t)\ \mathsf dt - \int_x^yf(x)\ \mathsf dt}{y-x} \right|\\ &= \left|\frac{\int_x^y f(t)\ \mathsf dt-\int_x^y f(x)\ \mathsf dt}{y-x} \right|\\ &= \left|\frac{\int_x^y (f(t)-f(x))\ \mathsf dt}{y-x} \right|\\ &\leqslant \frac{\int_x^y|f(t)-f(x)|\ \mathsf dt}{|y-x|}\\&\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon|y-x|}{|y-x|}\\ &=\varepsilon,
\end{align}
as was to be proved.